# Переносимость DLL и взаимодействие с различными компиляторами

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll, mingw

Вопросы такие:

1) Можно ли DLL, написанную на С++ и собранную с помощью MinGW, подключить к проекту, например, Visual Studio (MSVC) и наоборот. Будет ли она работать? Что на счет компиляторов (каждый собирает DLL по-разному или есть единый бинарный стандарт)?

2) Можно ли DLL, написанную на С++ использовать в проектах C#, Python и других языках программирования. Про Паскаль не спрашиваю, там обратный порядок передачи аргументов в функции (что тоже решаемо)

3) Что на счет 3d-party-libraries? Пример: есть freeglut, у которого есть версия как для MinGW, так и для MSVC компиляторов. Если существует единый бинарный интерфейс, то зачем распространяют несколько версий ?

Comment: c# и с++ - вообще коробки разной формы. В разных версиях с могут по разному называться типы, и могут по-разному делаться некоторые виды обьявлений (typedef и обязательное наличие typedef, разная привязка к interfaces, идентификация типов и т д)

Comment: В целом можно. Смотрите соглашения о вызовах: [wiki](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Соглашение_о_вызове), [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/k2b2ssfy.aspx).

Comment: Можно с помощью `#if` и `#ifdef` реализовывать куски для разных компиляторов (кроме с#) но, думаю, не стали заморачиваться.